# I can't integrate Facebook comments in my PHP blog?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to integrate FB comments under the articles on my PHP blog but I couldn't figure out how to do this?
FB comments is found here h**p://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

My blog is located here h**p://www.blog.aiwwan.com

*This is the HTML5 code I got from FB*

STEP 1
Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.
Their code here

STEP 2 Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

any one can help?

Answer (score 2):

You can add following code to your page, replace **appId** and **data-href** with your application ID from https://developers.facebook.com/apps and the URL of the page on your website that you want the comments to be associated with.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=105147492926472";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://borigami.com/content.php?article=291" data-num-posts="20" data-width="500">
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. 
Which page do you suggest to put the code to work on all pages that have posts?

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked but on a blank PHP test page I created.
When I place the code on themes.php file the blog won;t open??
I think the code need to placed somewhere else ??
I'm using Simple PHP blog  - http://sourceforge.net/projects/sphpblog/

Comment: Please try to get URL of current page and replace data-href by it. Each comment list is associated with a url.